# Ax 20012 SSRS Visual Studio crash

Tags: microsoft-dynamics

During implementation SSRS in Visual Studio, something crashed during Build process. 
Now it is not possible to open my report in VS.

Error:

"The item "\SSRS Reports\Report\" does not exist
in the repository. It may have been moved, renamed or deleted."

But report is still available in AOT, and also published version is still working.

Answer (score 0):

Partially I got back my report.

I downloaded rdl file from SQL reporting server. 
Renamed it to rdlc and opened in VS with Report Builder. At least it was possible to copy design layout to new report.